# Adding Author URL to Nav Menu via Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, urls, author

I'm looking to add the Author URL to the Nav Menu via a shortcode.

Here's the shortcode I registered:

```
add_shortcode( 'author_url', function() {
    return get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id() );
} );
```

After registering the shortcode, I tried using this plugin to add it to the nav menu: https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/

However, the shortcode output is **https//mysite.local** on my localhost

Notice how it's lacking the ':' after the https.

What's going on, and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The a tag has this output: http://https://mysite.local/author/username/. I'm adding the shortcode to a Custom Link. You can't see it, but it's http:// before the https://

Comment: Can you check the site URL you've configured under Settings, General? Have you missed out the colon there?

Comment: The site URL is correct. The a tag output looks like this: <a href="http:// https:// mysite.local/author/username/"></a> but without the space. For some reason it's appending an http:// before the https